# Should documentation use images with code snippets?

Tags: discussion, documentation

As per the title, should we be approving or rejecting documentation that uses images with code snippets?

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/10412?draftId=8968

Comment: In this specific example there are actually two images: One shows code, which should undeniably be in text. The other shows folder structure, which arguably can't be copy and pasted anyway. This particular example isn't all that great, but I can see some places where an image might be okay (showing which dialog to open in an IDE for example).

Comment: I think the folder structure is fine, just not the code bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think **NOT AT ALL**.

Screenshots of code in the body of questions is usually a main reason for having the question downvoted on SO, and the Documentation project should have high standard of examples, and to allow uses to copy the code and try it locally, without needing to rewrite the code in the image.

If people can't put the code in the example, the should not create it in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Images shouldn't be used since they harm usability and readability. Think about a user who wants to try an example on the fly, just copy/paste it and run the good example you provided them. If there's an image the user will have to rewrite it by hand, useless and time wasting, not what documentation aims to.

Also formatting code with markdown helps keeping a uniform style throughout the doc page; using images would just make it a mess of different styles/formatting/colors etc..